# What does the ownership parameter mean in sec's searching string?

Tags: sec, edgar

When you search info on specified company such as

[image]

There are three options for `Ownership`:include,exclude,only.What do they mean here?

Answer (score 1):

Insiders and significant owners of a company are required to file timely forms with the SEC for transactions made involving securities and derivatives of the company for which they are insiders as well as forms that report their holdings.

The ownership filter refers to these three forms:

- [Form 3](https://www.sec.gov/files/form3.pdf) - Initial statement of beneficial ownership of securities
- [Form 4](https://www.sec.gov/files/form4data%2C0.pdf) - Statement of changes in beneficial ownership of securities —- general instructions
- [Form 5](https://www.sec.gov/files/form5data%2C0.pdf) - Annual statement of changes in beneficial ownership of securities -— general instructions

The options therefore are to inlcude these filings, which could be many just for one year, with the search results; to exclude them; or to display only those filings.